# Rails 6 ActionController::Base.new.render_to_string

Tags: ruby-on-rails

After updating my Rails app from 5.2 to 6 the render_to_string stopped working.

Code

```
ActionController::Base.new.render_to_string(file: Rails.root.join('test.html.erb'), locals: { foo: 'bar' })
```

test.html.erb

```
<%= foo %>
```

Expected

```
bar
```

Current

```
<%= foo %>
```

It worked before, after updating to Rails 6 it simply outputs the file content without evaluating it.

PS.: I also tried using ApplicationController API (ApplicationController.render), same behavior.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Whats the context here? If you're doing this in a view or a helper you can just call `render_to_string` and render it with the view context of the current request. If you're doing it somewhere else like a service object you should pass the view context into the service.

Comment: As I said it worked just fine on 5.2, I never pass the view context into the service. I used to use it simply by `ActionController::Base.new.render_to_string`, now I figured there is a short way `ActionController::Base.render`. Checking the rails 6 code it looks like a breaking change: When using `file` option to `render/render_to_string` it uses a `RawFile` renderer.